# PHPBB user intergration, shows user is logged in however still makes user login

Tags: php, mysql, session, phpbb

I am trying to use a custom login on PHPBB3.1 and I am having some trouble. When a user logs in using my own script it will show in the forum as them being online. However, the forum still asks them to login?

This is the code I'm using:

```
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = __DIR__ . "/community/";
//$phpbb_root_path = (defined('community')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : '/community/';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);           
$user->session_begin();
$user->setup();
$auth->login($Username, $Password, $remember, 1, 0);
```

My login variables are set up like this:

```
$Username = $_POST["Username"];
$Password = $_POST["Password"];
```

Any help would be great thank you.

Comment: What's the return of the $auth->login line?
You can try add $auth->acl($user->data); after the session_begin();